# Extract 10 million records from sql server to excel files each containing 500k records

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I have created this query to partition 10 million records into tables of 500k records each.

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT
            DECLARE @RowsOfPage AS INT
        DECLARE @MaxTablePage  AS FLOAT 
        SET @PageNumber=1
        SET @RowsOfPage=500000
            SELECT @MaxTablePage = COUNT(*) 
                FROM [dbo].[50m_rows]
                where [Order Date] between '04/06/2020 12:00:00' and '10/05/2020 23:59:59'
        SET @MaxTablePage = CEILING(@MaxTablePage/@RowsOfPage)
        WHILE @MaxTablePage >= @PageNumber
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
                FROM [dbo].[50m_rows]
                where [Order Date] between '04/06/2020 12:00:00' and '10/05/2020 23:59:59'
                ORDER BY [Order Date] 
                OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsOfPage ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY
        SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1
        END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQc0k.png)

I need to extract these records into excel files that contains 500k records each.
**I need to create dynamic excel files for example:
First 500k --> file1.xlsx;
Second 500k --> file2.xlsx
and so on.**
I do not want to copy paste the records into each file.
Is there any way apart from using SSIS or extracting manually from SSMS?
For example using Batch?

Comment: Create a stored procedure that accepts your paging values as input parameters, call them directly from Excel or from whatever you're going to load Excel with.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Based on what you have said in the comment, I have created a **Windows Form application** to automate this task, I will prove my output image.

I think this will help you to solve your problem,
Let me start with a simple drawback of this, which is it is kinda manual not automation, meaning you have to give a query and a specific file, in your case file1.xlsx,file2.xlsx, etc

Show how it works? we can do it using **data export** here are the steps to do this.

Select your **database name**, then **Tasks**
and then **Export Data...**

the Wizard form shows you can click on **Next**
in **Data Source** you have to choose
**SQL Server Native Client**
, **server name** and your authentication method,
and finally your **database name**

Click on **Next**

For **Destination**, Select **Microsoft Excel**, **FileName, i.e File1**
and the **version**,
also, check First row has column names

Click on **Next**

Select where the data you want to copy, is from View or table?
or you can write a query you want, select **Write a query to specify the data transfer**

Click on **Next**

The query you are want to get the 500K result, is like this:
I have created a test table **tbl_Test, ID2, sName** and some 15 records of dummy data

```
select id2, sName from Testing.dbo.tbl_Test order by id2 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

here you want to run this query, what I am telling SQL Server is to give me the first 5 ROWS 1 to 5,
next time you can run:

```
select id2, sName from Testing.dbo.tbl_Test order by id2 OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

meaning give me 5 more rows after skipping the first 5, so ID from 6 to 10
and so on.

so, you have to run those steps let's say 4 times, for 4 different files, each file contains 500K of records.

Click on **Next**

SQL Server shows you the source and destination, here you can **Map columns and sheet names**, and also you can **preview** the result of your current query.

Click on **Next**

Now, SQL Server shows you the Review form, which displays where the data comes from and where to go, plus the mapping details, also, you can tell what will gonna happen if anything goes wrong.

Click on **Next**

Finally, Choose **Run immediately** and click on **Finish** if you don't want to see the summary form, or you can click on **Next** to view the **summary** form.

after the execution is complete it will show you what happened, how many records have been copied, and if anything went wrong it will show here you can click on Close or view the result of the operation as a **report**.

I will also provide the image of each step, hope I did something useful for you.

**Windows Form App 1:**
[image: WinForm1]

**Windows Form App 2:**
[image: WinForm2]

**Windows Form App 3:**
[image: WinForm3]

**Windows Form App 4:**
[image: WinForm4]

**Step 1:**
[image: Step1]

**Step 2:**
[image: Step 2]

**Step 3:**
[image: Step 3]

**Step 4:**
[image: Step 4]

**Step 5:**
[image: Step 5]

**Step 6:**
[image: Step 6]

**Step 7:**
[image: Step 7]

**Step 8:**
[image: Step 8]

**Step 9:**
[image: Step 9]

**Step 10:**
[image: Step 10]

**Step 11:**
[image: Step 11]

**Step 12:**
[image: Step 12]

Please let me know if you have any trouble with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @AwatITWork. It works, but it is a manual work. I was hoping if there is another solution so I don't have to do the same steps 20 times.

Comment: @AnswerQuestions, if you want I can create a Windows Form application using C# for you do to this. please let me know.

Comment: @AwaitITWork it would really help me.

Comment: @AnswerQuestions, sure, can you please join this room

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/243858/awat-and-answerquestions

Answer (score 0):

I hope your table is indexed. If it is not, please apply an index. Then, try to do the export in chunks, like this.

```
SELECT [URL] 
FROM [dbo].[siteentry] 
WHERE [Content] LIKE '' 
ORDER BY (some column)
    OFFSET 20000 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY
```

You have to order by some column, or the results will be essentially arbitrary.

See the link below for more info.

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-offset-fetch-feature-loading-large-volumes-of-data-using-limited-resources-with-ssis/