# Creating Excel files with OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, excel, extract

Following my previous question, [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857197/extract-10-million-records-from-sql-server-to-excel-files-each-containing-500k-r), I have reached till this point using sql-server, but I cannot create the excel files in my directory. Can anyone help me to create excel files? **( I need to create dynamic excel files for example: First 500k --> 1.xlsx; Second 500k --> 2.xlsx and so on.)** Attached you will find my T-SQL code.

```
Use Master
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO


USE [AdventureWorksDW2019]
GO

        DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT

        DECLARE @ExcelFileName as nVarchar(60) 
        SET @ExcelFileName = cast(@PageNumber as nvarchar)

        DECLARE @RowsOfPage AS INT
        DECLARE @MaxTablePage  AS FLOAT 
        SET @PageNumber=1
        SET @RowsOfPage=500000
            SELECT @MaxTablePage = COUNT(CustomerKey) 
                FROM [dbo].[DimCustomer]
                
        SET @MaxTablePage = CEILING(@MaxTablePage/@RowsOfPage)
    WHILE @MaxTablePage >= @PageNumber
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
                FROM [dbo].[DimCustomer]
                
                ORDER BY  CustomerKey
                OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsOfPage ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY
        

        DECLARE @FileName nvarchar(400) = @ExcelFileName+ '.xlsx'
        DECLARE @FullFileName nvarchar(400) = 'C:\Users\Desktop\CHANGE_LOGS_FOLDER\'+@FileName
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' +@FullFileName+''', ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') 
            SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[DimCustomer] '''+@ExcelFileName+''''

    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1

        END

Use Master
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 0
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 0
GO
```

Comment: [so] isn't a blogging site; questions don't have a "part 2" or a "continuation". Each question is it's *own* question. if you have a follow on question word it as its own question, not as a "continuation". If the question is part of the original question, it should be be an edit to the original one.

Comment: I have *guessed* a better title for your question; as the problem appears to be nothing about paging, but about the creation of your Excel files.

Comment: And my comment covers that; it should be it's own question in it's own right, not "part 2".

Comment: @Larnu my mistake, I am new in stack overflow. Thanks

Comment: Honestly - this isn't an appropriate function to implement with tsql. My suggestion is that you bulk, export the entire resultset into a CSV file (bcp comes to mind) and then use any file splitting tool to chop it into chunks. Excel has no issues with CSV files - so why do you focus on XLSX? In addition, the database engine will not generally have permissions to a user-specific directory like a virtual desktop folder.